# iOS - Check if Direct Carrier Billing is enable programmatically

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I would like to check programmatically if a user has the carrier billing enabled.

I'm reading the docs here. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/RequestPayment.html but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: You have no visibility as to how the user pays. You simply get told that the payment has been processed